# iOS unit testing async function not called

Tags: ios, swift

How to test that an async function is not called in iOS unit testing?

I know how to test that an async function IS called: by using XCTestExpectation and expectation fulfill. But how to test that a function is not called?

Context: There are four potential async function within a launcher, and with the specific argument, one of these functions should be called and the other three shouldn't. I know how to write a unit test to make sure that the function that needs to be called is called, but don't know how to write a test to test if the other three functions are not touched. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Q:** I know how to test that an async function IS called: by using XCTestExpectation and expectation fulfill. But how to test that a function is not called?*

Also with `XCTestExpectation`: it has an [`isInverted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation/2806573-isinverted) property, which is handy in such cases:

> Indicates that the expectation is not intended to happen.

So you set `XCTestExpectation` as:

```
let expectation = XCTestExpectation()
expectation.isInverted = true
```

and make the function that *should not run* will fulfil the expectation. So if the expectation did get fulfilled - you know the unwanted function did run, and the test will fail.